# sudo: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

Every time I try to use a sudo or ssh command, it returns with this error:

```
when:~ jackson1442$ sudo [insert any command here]
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I was messing with Python installs, and am not sure what I did to cause this. How can I permanently fix this?

macOS Sierra 10.12.4 16E195 
MacBook Pro 2016 
13" Touchbar

EDIT: here's the path:

```
when:~ jackson1442$ echo $PATH
’/usr/local/bin:??
```

Here is `.bash_profile`

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:��
```

Comment: @klanomath sorry about the delay Here it is: when:~ jackson1442$ echo $PATH
’/usr/local/bin:??

Comment: After commenting out or removing the last line and sourcing your profile the PATH should be at least `.../3.5/bin:.../3.6/bin:/.../2.7bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin` now (I omitted each `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` here).

Comment: @klanomath affirmative. It works! Not sure how that one at the end got there...

Comment: This is the culprit:  `export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:��`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your PATH is hosed!

First check your .bash_profile file with:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Prepend lines containing something like `export PATH="/... "` with a `#` to comment them out. Save the file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and exit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

Then check /etc/paths with: `/bin/cat /etc/paths`.

It should look like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

You can edit the file with `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/paths` if required.

If everything is fine enter `source ~/.bash_profile` or close the Terminal window and open a new one.

---

Now sudo should work again. Then check all `#export PATH=...` lines in your .bash_profile for potential errors. You may add them to your question to get help here.

Comment: There is nothing in `.bash.profile`

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I just had to quit terminal after commenting out that last funky line.

Comment: Thanks between using brew and conda the bash_profile had python PATH's all over the place. My work wasn't affected until we started to use ansible that insisted on using sudo. Though this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

***Magic Answer***

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Comment: This'll restore basic function to the current shell, but leaves out any additions to the standard `PATH` (e.g. the asker's additional versions of python), and it's not a permanent fix (that requires debugging the shell init files to find what's causing the problem).

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue for me immediately, but only till that particular terminal was open

Answer (score -6):

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Comment: If the OP states: *sudo [insert any command here] -bash: sudo: command not found* why should another command starting with `sudo ...` suddenly help/work?