# `sudo` and other commands not found in terminal in startup options mode

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, file-recovery

(EDITED for specificity)

When I use terminal in recovery mode (on a MacBook Pro with Apple silicon) a lot of bash commands seem to be missing and give me "command not found" errors when I try to run them. This goes for less basic commands like `systemsetup` that problem aren't standard bash, but also some really core ones like `sudo` and `man` and `du` (but not `df`). What causes this? I looked up another question ([sudo: command not found](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282299/sudo-command-not-found)) that suggested maybe there was an issue with my PATH, but the steps that were suggested to fix it didn't change anything:

```
-bash-3.2# /usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /usr/bin/nano: No such file or directory
-bash-3.2# /bin/cat /etc/paths
cat: /etc/paths: No such file or directory
-bash-3.2# export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
-bash-3.2# sudo echo test
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Is recovery mode running a *super* stripped down bash that doesn't recognize these commands? Or does this have to do with the way my system was damaged somehow? Or something else?

Comment: You are already running as `root`, so no `sudo` is required. BUT: Did you boot into recovery mode?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I booted into recovery mode

Comment: When you’re in Recovery, you should be able to SSH right into the the machine.   You need to use the IP address instead as all of the `sshd.config` settings including SSh keys will be different as this is a different OS than the installed one.

Comment: @Allan how can I find the IP address for the machine?

Comment: `ifconfig en0` or `ifconfig en1`. Whatever the device name for your network connection

Comment: @Allan I created another question specifically about how to connect remotely, instead of carrying on this conversation in the comments of the sudo command issue question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459891/how-to-access-and-copy-files-from-a-connected-mac-in-share-disk-mode-via-termi

Comment: I know.  This conversation can be moved to chat if necessary.  Creating another question will likely get it closed. I also left a comment that the command you used was incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146024/discussion-between-empiromancer-and-allan).

Comment: You can’t treat the Recovery environment the same as your normal environment; you’re booting a completely different image of macOS.  First, when you’re in Terminal, you’re root and there’s no need for `sudo`.  Also, `~/.bash_profile` won’t exist.  Second, before setting path variables, see what the path is *first*; just type `echo $PATH`.  Let’s start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you're running as root so sudo is not needed.

However, to elaborate more, you're not booting from your regular system - many tools will not be available. There is nothing wrong with your system. It is stripped down to the bare minimum to allow you to interact with your disk and diagnose problems.

Comment: So is there any way to get access to a tool like du?