# How to copy files from a Mac in "Disk Sharing" mode to another Mac?

Tags: command-line, ssh, sharing, smb, data-recovery

I have a borked Macbook Pro running apple silicon, and to recover files from it I've shared Macintosh HD in "Shared Disk" mode via startup options and connected it to a working mac with a USB-C cable. I can view and move around the file system of the borked mac in finder - but I can't copy the contents of my User folder over (I get a -36 error). How can I copy the files from my damaged mac over to the new one?

What I've tried so far:

1. Run `dot_clean` on the user folder (inside a recovery mode terminal on the old computer). RESULT: `dot_clean` command not recognized
2. ssh into the old computer from the new one. RESULT: hangs until it times out or says the connection was refused. Either I have the wrong IP addresses (using ones I found from running `ifconfig -a | grep -i inet` on the old computer)
3. Enable remote login on old computer to fix ssh problems using `systemsetup -setremotelogin on`. RESULT: systemsetup command not found

What's the best way for me to successfully copy my old files from the broken computer to the new one?

Comment: The command is `ifconfig` with an “f” not a “p”

Comment: @Allan ah, right, and that's the command I ran on my computer too. I just mistyped it in this question. Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit all over the place and asks several things at once (as does the `sudo` question you posted earlier, especially after the edits). It might be better to focus on the problem you want to solve and not so much guessing about potential solutions and mentioning how they fail.

Comment: Alright, I can tighten up the questions after my chat with @Allan. I just wanted to understand the problems I was facing properly rather than running some cryptic code and calling it a day - and I suppose I misunderstood the Ask Different etiquette for posts as well.

Comment: There are a lot of valid questions in your post, but most of them would be better asked separately (and independent of the actual problem you want to solve). Some of them probably are even answered on AD already.